# Generate different dimension tuples in python

Tags: python

I started learning python recently but i'm stuck in this question that i saw somewhere.

The input will be a number `n` followed by a *list of n numbers*. I have to generate different combination tuples eliminating one element each time:

Input:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

Expected Output:

```
[(1,),(2,3,4)]
[(1,2),(3,4)]
[(1,2,3),(4,)]
[(1,2,3,4)]
```

As you can see one element from the tuple is getting out in each sequence.

This is what i tried:

```
 n=int(input())

    my_num=[]
    my_list=[]
    my_num=input().split(" ")
    my_num=list(map(int,my_num))

    for i in my_num:
        temp_num=list(itertools.combinations(my_num,i))
        my_list.append(temp_num)
```

This is what i got:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Now i had to pick elements manually which is obviously not allowed. 
I know i have to do something with last element in each list but not able to figure it out. Please Help! Thank you!

Also how to refer to an specific element like what if i need to print only `(2,3,4)` in the above generated 1st list. How to refer to it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Always use the generic [python] tag for Python questions. If it is necessary, use a version specific tag *in addition* to the generic tag.

Comment: Okay sure! I just use python 3.x so I thought maybe using that is more relevant. Anyhow I will from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate an index through the range of the length of the input list and slice the list at the index accordingly. The last list in the expected output does not require slicing and has only one tuple (as opposed to two in the lists before it) so you can just yield it directly:

```
def slices(l):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        yield [tuple(l[:i]), tuple(l[i:])]
    yield [tuple(l)]
```

so that:

```
list(slices([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

returns:

```
[[(1,), (2, 3, 4)], [(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3), (4,)], [(1, 2, 3, 4)]]
```

Comment: `len(l) + 1`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the second `yield` to account for the last odd item in the expected output.

Comment: How do i refer to a specific element? like `(2,3,4)` in `[(1,),(2,3,4)]`

Comment: @Me-So-Cool That would be `list(slices([1, 2, 3, 4]))[0][1]` (use square brackets to access a list/tuple item by index).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is just a simple partitioning scheme.  E.g.

```
>>> def partitions(tup):
...     for idx in range(1, len(tup) + 1):
...         yield ((tup[:idx], tup[idx:]))
...
>>> list(partitions((1, 2, 3, 4)))
[((1,), (2, 3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2, 3), (4,)), ((1, 2, 3, 4), ())]
```

I would recommend, as I did, still including an empty tuple in the last case so that you consistently return a pair of tuples for each item.